# Header file seem to have it's enums defined in a .lib library

Tags: c++, kinect, mingw-w64

Update at the bottom.

I have a Kinect V2 laying around and wanted to see if I could do something fun with it so I downloaded the SDK, MinGW-w64, and the C/C++ for Visual Studio Code extension and started hacking away at acquiring the sensor and reading the infrared data source and this is what I have so far:

#include "test.h"

```
int main() {
    HRESULT sensorAcquisition = aquireSensor();

    return 0;
}

HRESULT aquireSensor() {

    HRESULT hr = GetDefaultKinectSensor(&m_pKinectSensor);
    
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // Initialize the Kinect and get the infrared reader
    IInfraredFrameSource* pInfraredFrameSource = NULL;

    hr = m_pKinectSensor->Open();

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb931994(v=msdn.10)
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = m_pKinectSensor->get_InfraredFrameSource(&pInfraredFrameSource);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pInfraredFrameSource->OpenReader(&m_pInfraredFrameReader);
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Along with the header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v2.0_1409\inc\Kinect.h"

HRESULT aquireSensor();

// InfraredSourceValueMaximum is the highest value that can be returned in the InfraredFrame.
// It is cast to a float for readability in the visualization code.
#define InfraredSourceValueMaximum static_cast<float>(USHRT_MAX)

// The InfraredOutputValueMinimum value is used to set the lower limit, post processing, of the
// infrared data that we will render.
// Increasing or decreasing this value sets a brightness "wall" either closer or further away.
#define InfraredOutputValueMinimum 0.01f 

// The InfraredOutputValueMaximum value is the upper limit, post processing, of the
// infrared data that we will render.
#define InfraredOutputValueMaximum 1.0f

// The InfraredSceneValueAverage value specifies the average infrared value of the scene.
// This value was selected by analyzing the average pixel intensity for a given scene.
// Depending on the visualization requirements for a given application, this value can be
// hardcoded, as was done here, or calculated by averaging the intensity for each pixel prior
// to rendering.
#define InfraredSceneValueAverage 0.08f

/// The InfraredSceneStandardDeviations value specifies the number of standard deviations
/// to apply to InfraredSceneValueAverage. This value was selected by analyzing data
/// from a given scene.
/// Depending on the visualization requirements for a given application, this value can be
/// hard coded, as was done here, or calculated at runtime.
#define InfraredSceneStandardDeviations 3.0f

// Current Kinect
IKinectSensor* m_pKinectSensor;

// Infrared reader
IInfraredFrameReader*  m_pInfraredFrameReader;
```

When I compile this using:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Kinect\\v2.0_1409\\Lib\\x64",
                "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Kinect\\v2.0_1409\\inc"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "forcedInclude": [],
            "browse": {
                "path": []
            },
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

It throws a lot of the following errors:

```
use of enum '_KinectCapabilities' without a previous declaration
```

The enums are referenced here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect/dn758672(v=ieb.10)

They seem to require the library Kinect20.lib.

I added the folder it is into my include path but that doesn't fix the issue and after A LOT of googling and changing the compiler configuration I've hit a wall.

Any ideas?

Disclaimer, I'm a noob when it comes to compilers and C++ so don't be mean if the solution is trivial.

UPDATE: (Forgive me if I say something wrong, compiling and c++ isn't my strong suit)

The problem:
So as a few people commented and I suspected there seemed to be a problem with my compiling and linking, especially using MinGW-w64. There was a static library, namely "Kinect20.lib" that was needed for "Kinect.h" to work as I understand it and the MinGW-w64 compiler either couldn't handle .lib or I was to stupid/impatient to make it work.

The solution:
I downloaded Visual Studio community 2019 and copy/pasted my previously written code into a new project, added paths to "Kinect.h" and "Kinect20.lib" to the c++ dependencies and linker directory/files respectively. Made sure to use x86 everywhere.

This is where it gets annoying... I ran the debugger and I got the same errors as before but I clicked one of the errors and it opened "Kinect.h" and all the errors disappeared, the code ran and my Kinect turned on!

I hope this can help anyone in the same position as me and also if you read through this and have any comments for me where I said something wrong or where I could improve in some way I'd be super grateful for feedback!

Comment: Can you post more of the error (like what file it's in)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/kinect/dn758683(v=ieb.10) seems to suggest you only have to `#include <kinect.h>`, which looks like what you've already done. (Kinect20.lib would have the functions, not types or enum values) You never need a lib/object file in your include path, so `Kinect\\v2.0_1409\\Lib\\x64` is probably not right.

Comment: The library headers are most likely msvc-specific and tricky to compile with mingw64. If you can't find someone who has already made ms libraries to work with gcc then maybe try if you have better luck with libfreenect or the like.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Artyer and @Öö-Tib! I used your comments and solved the issue and updated the post!